# Show banner once per browser session using asp.net and cookies

Tags: c#, asp.net, webforms

I want to show a banner only once per browser session.

```
 <asp:Panel ID="Panel1" runat="server">
<img src="path"/>
 </asp:Panel>
```

I want to achieve this using cookie from code-behind file.

My code is below but the banner keeps showing ever time, How i achieve this in bets manner

```
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
    if (!IsPostBack)
    {
    //Set Banner Cookie
    HttpCookie BannerCookie = new HttpCookie("ShowBanner");
    BannerCookie.Value = "YES";
     Response.Cookies.Add(bannercookie)
     Panel1.Visible = False;
    //Do Somthing...
    ShowPageDetails();
    ShowBanner();

    }
    else
    {
    //Do Somthing
    Panel1.Visible = False;
    ShowPageDetails();
    ShowBanner();
    }
}

public void ShowBanner()
{
 HttpCookie BannerCookie = Request.Cookies["ShowBanner"];
 if (BannerCookie != null)
 {
 Panel1.Visible = True;
            BannerCookie.Value = null;
            Response.Cookies.Add(BannerCookie);
 }
else
{
Panel1.Visible = false;
}
}
```

UPDATE:  I tried the solution mentioned below by `Ajay` but that is not working properly either it generates error when cookie is null or always show the banner.

I am not sure how i can change the logic so that banner will only show one per each browser session. I tried several ways but didn't get it working. Any-other solution that might work from code-behind.

Comment: Where are you adding cookie in response : Response.Cookies.Add(bannercookie) ?

Comment: Sorry Missed that part ... while copying ..I will updated it now.

Comment: I am setting value for cookie on page load and when i show the banner then i rest cookie to null value.... but it i snot working as desired. I am doing something wrong logically.

Comment: check showbanner code in my answer.

Answer (score 0):

You ShowBanner() logic needs to be corrected , when cookie is not present show else dont your were doing reverse , also on page load dont add cookie everytime

I want to show a banner only once per browser session.

I want to achieve this using cookie from code-behind file.

My code is below but the banner keeps showing ever time, How i achieve this in bets manner

```
public void ShowBanner()
{
 HttpCookie BannerCookie = Request.Cookies["ShowBanner"];
 if (BannerCookie != null)
 {
 Panel1.Visible = false;
 }
else{
Panel1.Visible = true;
}
}
```

On page load add cookie only if not present

```
HttpCookie BannerCookie = Request.Cookies["ShowBanner"];
 if (BannerCookie == null)
{
    BannerCookie = new HttpCookie("ShowBanner");
    BannerCookie.Value = "YES";
     Response.Cookies.Add(bannercookie)
}
```

Comment: It is giving me error "A local variable cant be declared in this scope......" for this line of code `HttpCookie BannerCookie = new HttpCookie("ShowBanner");` on page load part of code

Comment: edit the code , no need declare HttpCookie again inside ShowBanner() if

Comment: But error is second part of the code you have mentioned ... not the showbanner() part error descrption `A local variable named 'BannerCookie' cannot be declared in this scope because it would give a different meaning to 'BannerCookie', which is already used in a 'parent or current' scope to denote something else`

Answer (score 0):

Create a session variable:

```
    if(Session["whatever"] == null)
    {
         // show the post
    }
    else
    {
         Session["whatever"] = 0;
    }
```